# Java - How many times each lottery ball appear?

Tags: java

I have loaded lottery results CSV file to the java. This means I have a arraylist with each draw. Each arraylist item stored draw results of a particular week (ball1,ball2.....ball6, bonusball). Each draw consist of 6 numbers and bonus number, in between (1-59).
If we need to calculate how many times each ball appear, do we need to create 59 variables?
Are there any method to do this easily.

Comment: I suggest you use an `int[]` to hold the count of each ball number. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Hi Peter, Is that int[i] with for loop?

Comment: Yes, though it would be more like `int[] count = new int[60]; while(scanner.hasNextInt()) count[scanner.nextInt()]++;`

Comment: Highly appreciated Peter,

Comment: I suggest you follow the code I suggested.  The code can only go inside a method.  This doesn't check anything, nor does it need to.

Comment: Thanks again Peter. I will try the code yo given.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's another shameless effort by a lazy student to con others into doing their cheating for them.

Comment: Using an array is a natural choice here. Using a struct or Class doesn't make sense except to wrap the array.

Comment: I created variables like this: int[] abc;
      abc = new int[59];
      for (int i=1;i<=abc.length;i++){
      abc[i]=0;
     }

Comment: Now if I use for loop:  for (int i=0; i < draws.size(); i++) { if (draws.get(i).ball1=abc[i]){ abc[i]=abc[i]+1;}

Comment: This will give an error message as integer types not support to Boolean??

Comment: Any suggestion Peter?

Comment: Arrays start at `0` and the last values is `array.length - 1` Arrays are always filled with `0` to start with so you don't need to zero out the array to start with.  You don't need to check any thing as I said before. This means you don't need to use `if`.  Just increment the value drawn (not the index of the value drawn)

Comment: Thanks Peter. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays start at 0 so if you want to use index number `59` you need 60 elements.

```
List<Integer> drawn = ...
int[] count = new int[60];
for (int draw : drawn)
     count[draw]++;
for (int i = 1; i < count.length; i++)
     System.out.println(i + ": " + count[i]);
```

Comment: Many thanks  Peter. Hopefully I can modify the above code. I got an arraylist, each element got 7 numbers for each week. no of weeks=size of the arraylist. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Java's an object oriented language.  I'd recommend encapsulating a single drawing as a class that you can interact with.

There's no need to create a variable for each ball number.  I'd have a Random instance to generate random values between 1 and the max ball number:

```
Random random = new Random(); // with seed for testing.
int ballValue = random.nextInt(numBalls) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case I have array of draw numbers. Form this array list I need to calculate 'how many times has each ball appeared'

Comment: I think the above method is ok for generate numbers.

Comment: I could write it for you.  Or you could create a Map that keeps number of appearances for each number.  That data structure is separate from the drawing you present to users.  if random number generator is working properly, wouldn't you agree that the Map of frequencies should show that each number appears 1/n of the time, all the same?

Comment: my assignment is  write it without using map. Need to use iterative style. I am new to java.

Comment: Then array it is.  The index is the key; the value is the count of appearances by that number.  Increment the appropriate one every time the random number generator gives you its answer.

Comment: Highly appreciated. Can I create this array within a method?

Comment: You should create it in the constructor of the Java object I'm advising that you start with.

Comment: Thaks again. Highly appreciated

Comment: Struct. Any chance can you give me the code to create 59 integer variables within a method using an array please?

Comment: I have the whole thing written.  No, I won't give it to you.  What's the point of homework if you don't attempt it?   Solve the problem by breaking it into pieces: Read a .csv; parse each line into tokens; turn the tokens into numbers; increment the count for each number.

Comment: Thats fine. I didnt ask the whole program to write. I just ask the format of creating an integer array within a method. I can create an array, but I dont have the idea to allocate them to variables.

Comment: only asked, ' code to create 59 integer variables within a method ' , and not the other part.